# Populate SQL Azure from REST API

Tags: sql-server, r, azure

I'm a newbie in this field, but my goal is to import data from a 3rd party API to my SQL Server hosted in Azure. To access the data from the API and clean it I'm using an R script.

My idea would be to schedule a job on a Virtual Machine that runs the R script and prepares the data so it can be imported to SQL Server and automate this process too.

Is this a good approach? Since Visual Studio "accepts" R would it be possible to automate everything there? Any direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A more industry standard approach would be to use Azure Data Factory to operationalize these types of processes:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/

You can import data and merge it from any where, schedule the job, and integrate custom code including R and Azure Machine Learning.  Its built for exactly this sort of workload.

Not sure why this is getting down-voted, but I'll provide a few more methods that are fairly common using these same tools:
1.  Azure Batch
2.  U-SQL
3.  Hadoop (with R on top)

DataFactory can be scheduled and integrated into the fully ecosystem, hence why I use this instead of a VM.  You could use a VM, but then you are writing a lot more code.